# WFLYSRV0025: 601 services are lazy, passive or on-demand)

Tags: jboss, keycloak

I am trying to install keycloak and ran standalone.sh where I am getting below error. Not sure what is wrong.

```
16:59:24,108 INFO  [org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 63) HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
16:59:24,116 WARN  [org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 63) HHH000431: Unable to determine H2 database version, certain features may not work
16:59:24,158 INFO  [org.hibernate.envers.boot.internal.EnversServiceImpl] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 63) Envers integration enabled? : true
16:59:24,648 INFO  [org.hibernate.orm.beans] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 63) HHH10005002: No explicit CDI BeanManager reference was passed to Hibernate, but CDI is available on the Hibernate ClassLoader.
16:59:24,707 INFO  [org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.Version] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 63) HV000001: Hibernate Validator 6.0.18.Final
16:59:25,902 INFO  [org.hibernate.hql.internal.QueryTranslatorFactoryInitiator] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 63) HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
16:59:26,673 INFO  [org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy_jaxrs.i18n] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 63) RESTEASY002225: Deploying javax.ws.rs.core.Application: class org.keycloak.services.resources.KeycloakApplication
16:59:26,674 INFO  [org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy_jaxrs.i18n] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 63) RESTEASY002205: Adding provider class org.keycloak.services.filters.KeycloakTransactionCommitter from Application class org.keycloak.services.resources.KeycloakApplication
16:59:26,675 INFO  [org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy_jaxrs.i18n] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 63) RESTEASY002200: Adding class resource org.keycloak.services.resources.JsResource from Application class org.keycloak.services.resources.KeycloakApplication
16:59:26,675 INFO  [org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy_jaxrs.i18n] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 63) RESTEASY002200: Adding class resource org.keycloak.services.resources.ThemeResource from Application class org.keycloak.services.resources.KeycloakApplication
16:59:26,675 INFO  [org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy_jaxrs.i18n] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 63) RESTEASY002205: Adding provider class org.keycloak.services.error.KeycloakErrorHandler from Application class org.keycloak.services.resources.KeycloakApplication
16:59:26,676 INFO  [org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy_jaxrs.i18n] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 63) RESTEASY002210: Adding provider singleton org.keycloak.services.util.ObjectMapperResolver from Application class org.keycloak.services.resources.KeycloakApplication
16:59:26,676 INFO  [org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy_jaxrs.i18n] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 63) RESTEASY002220: Adding singleton resource org.keycloak.services.resources.RobotsResource from Application class org.keycloak.services.resources.KeycloakApplication
16:59:26,676 INFO  [org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy_jaxrs.i18n] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 63) RESTEASY002220: Adding singleton resource org.keycloak.services.resources.admin.AdminRoot from Application class org.keycloak.services.resources.KeycloakApplication
16:59:26,676 INFO  [org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy_jaxrs.i18n] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 63) RESTEASY002220: Adding singleton resource org.keycloak.services.resources.WelcomeResource from Application class org.keycloak.services.resources.KeycloakApplication
16:59:26,676 INFO  [org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy_jaxrs.i18n] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 63) RESTEASY002220: Adding singleton resource org.keycloak.services.resources.RealmsResource from Application class org.keycloak.services.resources.KeycloakApplication
16:59:26,761 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 63) WFLYUT0021: Registered web context: '/auth' for server 'default-server'
16:59:26,869 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 55) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "keycloak-server.war" (runtime-name : "keycloak-server.war")
16:59:26,902 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0212: Resuming server
16:59:26,904 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0060: Http management interface listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990/management
16:59:26,904 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0051: Admin console listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990
16:59:26,904 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0025: Keycloak 9.0.3 (WildFly Core 10.0.3.Final) started in 12274ms - Started 590 of 885 services (601 services are lazy, passive or on-demand)
```

Comment: I don't see any errors in those log messages.

Comment: its getting hung at Keycloak 9.0.3 (WildFly Core 10.0.3.Final) started in 12274ms - Started 590 of 885 services (601 services are lazy, passive or on-demand)

Comment: That's normal. It means the server is up ad running. If you're using Linux you can do something like `$JBOSS_HOME/bin/standalone.sh &` to launch the process in the background.